# How to stream new data to clients browser when index.html change, without the need of refreshing or reloading the web page

Tags: javascript, html

I am new on Html. What i need is this.
I have an index.html file on a server which is blank.
I open it and write some text inside the body all the time.
What i want is that when i save the html, 
the new data to appear on my clients browser 
without the need to refresh or reload the page.
I have no idea on how to do it,so i haven't try anything.
Is it possible? Is it simple?

Comment: You can use Ajax to change the content on the page dynamically, combine with a server sided script to track the changes.

Comment: You could use the Sublime Text code editor with the LiveReload plugin to get the result you require. Otherwise, look into setting up something like BrowserSync or LiveServer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sample javascript code to read an online url and update the content container with the result.

I couldn't find a simple live update page so used my own website readme in github...

```js
var timeout = 2000,
  index = 1,
  cancel = false,
  url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/petjofi/krivoshiev.com/master/README.md';

function update() {
  updateIndex();
  load(url, done);
  if (!cancel) setTimeout(update, timeout);
}

function updateIndex() {
  document.getElementById("index").innerHTML = index++;
}

function done(result) {
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = result;
}

function load(url, callback) {
  var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
      callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
  }
  xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true); // true for asynchronous 
  xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="update()">start</button>
<button onclick="cancel=true">stop</button>
<span>updating: <span id="index">0</span></span>

<div style="margin-top: 20px" id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Petar Krivoshiev Exactly what i need. Is it possible to remove the buttons and start updating when page loads? Also if i want to get the data from a csv file on my desktop what i need to change on your script? Again thank you very much for the code!!!

Comment: This way you won't be able to stop the script until you close the tab. Delete the buttons and the span if needed and call the update just before the function: `update();  function update() { ...` Also if you remove the span you don't need updateIndex().

Comment: With chrome it will be difficult to read the local (Desktop) file. I tried Firefox Dev Edition and the following worked. Put the html file with the script on the desktop (Example: test.html). Change the url property to point to the csv file (Example: `url="test.csv;"`). Open it with FF and enjoy. It will may be work with IE too.

Comment: Thank you Petar. I ll modify to my needs... :)